# Why is pylab.plot() making my python in spyder crash?

Tags: python

Whenever I use the function pylab.plot(), it causes spyder to crash and show an error

This is the code I'm using:

```
def myplot():
    x = ([1,2,3],[2,4,6])
    pylab.plot(x)
```

This is the error message I've got:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPEnh.png)

My friends are running the exact same code without an error - I can't work out what I'm doing wrong?

Every time this happens I have to open a new console to make spyder even function which needless to say is extremely irritating.

I'd appreciate any help, thank you,
Ben

Comment: Try reinstalling.

Comment: Cheers, I've reinstalled now and it works fine - I've got no idea what was wrong

Comment: You never know. Sometimes, even the files themselves get corrupted by an accidental file write operation -- and then reinstalling should fix it.